# Отсортировать объекты в новую коллекцию

Tags: c#

Есть два наследуемых класса. Нужно в новую коллекцию отсортировать их по увеличению `val`, но сначала должны идти объекты `A` потом `B`.

```
abstract class AB { }
class A : AB { public int val; public A(int i) { val = i; } }
class B : AB { public int val; public  B(int i) { val = i; } }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<AB> l = new List<AB> { new A(2), new B(7), new A(1), new B(5) };
    var newList = /* ? ? ? */
}
```

Comment: `l.OrderBy(x => x.GetType() == typeof(A) ? 0 : 1);`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov спс

Comment: @Kir_Antipov это  только по типу, надо ж ещё и по значению, типа `ThenBy` и все такое

Comment: @tym32167: я не вижу у ТС этого в условии)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov  `Нужно в новую коллекцию отсортировать их по увеличению val ....` ?

Comment: @tym32167... упс...) Я слеп хД